# email address format sql oracle

Tags: sql, database

I want to insert email address as firstname.last_name@domain.com in my table 
if i do the following:

```
insert into employee
    values ('EMP01','Mona','Ali',first_name||'.'||LAST_NAME||'@dentalHouse.com');
```

i get column not allowed here. Help please. Dont complicate the answer though.

is there any way to get around rather than typing name again ?

Thank you

Comment: what are `first_name` and `LAST_NAME`? column names i assume, but which row do you expect them to be coming from? this just doesn't make sense..

Comment: If you want this all in a single insert, there's no way around repeating the name values.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you want `update`:

```
update employee
    set emailaddress = first_name || '.' || LAST_NAME || '@dentalHouse.com'
    where empid = 'EMP01';
```

I am just guessing what the id column is named.

Comment: Thank you, i will insert the necessary data and go with this, means alot for quick response.